# Storing a variable to web server

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, webserver

I have a page on my site where you can play a game. When you die in the game, a function called "playerIsDead();" is called, then the game closes (The game screens are prompt();s and confirm();s shown one after another, so by "the game closes", I mean the page stops showing popup messages.). The playerIsDead(); Function:

```
    var playerIsDead = function() {

        confirm(deathMsg);

        confirm(deathMsg2);

        confirm(deathMsg3);

    };
```

I want to make the function increase a variable, totalDeathCount, by one each time, like this:

```
    var playerIsDead = function() {

        confirm(deathMsg);

        confirm(deathMsg2);

        confirm(deathMsg3);

        totalDeathCount++;

    };
```

So, my question is, how can I store totalDeathCount to the server, so I can display it on the page? I don't want it to show how many deaths have happened locally, I want it to show how many worldwide deaths have occurred.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use a database.

Comment: May you should look at `rest` and `api'`

Comment: You could use Jquery's AJAX methods to send the data to a web server and store the information in a database like MYSQL there. This is however basic stuff when it comes to designing web-apps. So maybe take some beginners tutorials first.

Comment: Cagy79 It is not that I am a begginer, it is just I studied more js for applications, and not so much for websites.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MySQL database and store the value using PHP. Or you could simply use javascript's localStorage to store them locally on the device. 
`var newDeathCount = localStorage.getItem('totalDeathCount') + 1;
localStorage.setItem('totalDeathCount',newDeathCount);`

Then you basically stored how many times they have died. Not in a web server but this is an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Decide how and create something to persist the information. E.g. write it to a file, store it in a database, etc.

2) Write a simple php script to store the data. (or implement it as part of your existing php backend if available)

3) Make an ajax post request to send the data to the script.

For implementation details use google and your imagination. ;)

Comment: I know the process, I need to know how to do it, but thanks anyways!

Comment: @Ampck — Which bit of the process do you not understand and are unable to find a decent guide using a search engine?